Flutter Quill Text Editing Issue
When testing locally, everything worked fine, but after deploying to the server, the text editing section appears gray. What could be the problem? (The toolbar icons display correctly.)
Setup
AWS + Express + Flutter + MySQL
Built locally and uploaded directly to the build/web folder (not using Git)
Flutter 3.22.2, the latest version, using Android Studio
The quill installation path is not a regular flutter folder, but the aws server did not install it separately.
General files:/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.22.2/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services
quill file:/Users/user123/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_quill-9.4.6/lib/src/models/config/toolbar
enter image description here
enter image description here

Don't you see any overflow logs when debugging?
